# Непредвиденное появление: 1

Tags: cmd

Спасите CMD! Есть такой батник:

```
echo OFF

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo %1
echo -

set "tailA="

for %%A in (%*) do (
    if %tailA% EQU 1 echo %%A
    set tailA=1
)
```

Задача в том, чтобы обойти все переданные скрипту аргументы за исключением первого и выполнить для каждого некую команду, здесь для примера просто echo. Так вот, при запуске выдает ошибку:

> Непредвиденное появление: 1.

Comment: Что должна, по вашему, делать вот эта строка `set "tailA="`?

Comment: Создавать переменную `tailA` взял от сюда https://ss64.com/nt/if.html

Comment: @Kromster Не нужно править, то что не нужно править.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая проблема была в том, что после подстановки `%tailA%`, условие `if` разворачивалось в:

```
if EQU 1 A   
rem A это значение %%A
```

То есть объявление `set "tailA="` задает пустую переменную буквально, на месте `%tailA%` пусто! Соответственно интерпретатор CMD не мог разобрать такое выражение и честно об этом сообщал. Эти проблемы сразу видны если убрать `echo OFF` в самом начале скрипта.

Вторая проблема была в том, что повторное присваивание `tailA` действительно не выполнялось на моей системе (Windows 10). Происходило это потому, что не включалось расширение `EnableDelayedExpansion`, а не включалось оно потому что расширения были запрещены! Чтобы разрешить расширения есть другой ключ `EnableExtensions`. Короче, работающий скрипт:

```
echo OFF

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion


echo %1

set _tailA=0

for %%A in (%*) do (    
    if !_tailA! equ 1 (
        echo %%A
    ) else (
        set /A _tailA=1
    )
)
```